# Save image in original resolution with imfindcircle plot in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, save, resolution

I have a really long picture where I use imfindcircles on. But I need to check if the right ones are found. It is a 158708x2560 logical.

So I have:

```
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(I,[15 35],'ObjectPolarity','bright','Sensitivity',0.91);
figure(1)
imshow(I)
viscircles(centers,radii);
```

and I want to save that output you see in the figure box (binary image with circles on it) to a image file. File format doesn't matter as long as it has the same resolution of 158708x2560 pixel.

Every suggestion I find online alters the resolution or makes the image broader, like when saving the figure directly you get a huge grey border and resolution goes down.
What would also work is a way to zoom into the figure but the zoom option in the figure menu does not magnify correctly. It does magnify but the image stays really thin so you can't see a thing.

Matrix: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh9wakimc7atfhg/I.mat?dl=0

There are two round spots repeating. I want to find those, not the others. And export the image with the circles plotted over it.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Have you tried `print` (and looked at the various options available)?

Comment: Have you considered using `export_fig` from MATLAB FEX? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Comment: Print doesn't work because it doesn't keep the resolution/dpi. But I will try export_fig.

Comment: export_fig changes the resolution to 17x829px instead of the desired 2560x158708px. You can image that it's hard to see something on this.

Comment: I included the image now, just download it and try it yourself to see what I mean.